# How to remove Google+ Circles contacts in Gmail contacts?

Tags: gmail, google-plus, google-contacts

I see that in my Gmail contacts there are duplicated contacts that come from Google+ as below snapshot.

I really don't want those contacts appear in my Gmail. How can I get rid of it?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: I wish I could +1000 this question and attract Google's direct attention to it. I follow 5000 people just for fun because I like diverse new interesting stuff to appear in the stream. But I don't know these people and don't plan to call/email them ever, this is wildly ridiculous that all of them get added to my contacts.

Answer (score 4):

Short of deleting your Google+ profile, you cannot. There is no setting within Gmail to remove or hide that set of contacts.

Some custom CSS might allow you to hide them, but they won't actually be removed.

Answer (score 2):

In my Gmail Contacts 
I created a New Group called "GPlus". 
I selected all of the Google+ contacts from "Other Contacts" and moved them to "GPlus".
Then I selected everything in "GPlus" and unchecked "My Contacts".
Now each time I follow someone in Google+, I go into "Other Contacts", move them to "GPlus", and deselect "My Contacts".

If you do it this way, everything still shows up in Circles.

Comment: This seems to be the answer. I'll check and back to you later.

Answer (score -1):

Do the following:

1. circles
2. circle actions
3. edit circle

Type the name of the person in

> type the name box

When the name shows up, delete it.

Comment: But this unfollows the user in Google+, right? I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem with people I never followed or invited into my circles, so I don't think this will solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Only thing you can do is to change the name of the person in your contact according to his google+ profile name. That's how he will not appear twice in your contact list.